# Using the Theorem of Variable Change in $\mathbb{R}^m$ to solve a limit of volumes.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m , f \in C^{1}, U \subseteq_{op} \mathbb{R}^m, a \in U$ such that $f'(a):\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is an isomorphism. Show that $ \lim_{r \rightarrow a^{+}} \frac{ vol(f(\bar{B}(a;r)))}{ vol(\bar{B}(a;r))} = |\det(f'(a))|$

Variable Change Theorem: Let $h:U\rightarrow V$, $h$ is a $C^1$ difeomorphism between $U,V \subseteq_{op} \mathbb{R}^n$, $X \subseteq U$ a J-measurable compact set and $f:h(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ integrable function. Then $f \circ h:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable and: $\int_{h(X)} f(y)dy = \int_{X} f(h(x)) . |\det h'(x)|dx$

I'm having such a hard time on how to apply the above theorem for solving my problem. My first doubt is if $f$ in the problem is a difeomorphism.
What I tried to do is let $\epsilon>0$; since $U$ is an open set, take $\bar{B}(a;\frac2{\epsilon})$ which is compact J-measurable. Consider the characteristic function $\chi: f(\bar{B}(a;r)) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, which is integrable. Then $\int_{f(\bar{B}(a;r))} \chi (y)dy = \int_{\bar{B}(a;r)} \chi(f(x)) . |\det f'(x)|dx$.

I'm not sure what to do next to aproach that limit, neither if my change of variables makes sense...

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like $a$ turned into $0.$

Comment: yes, edited. thanks

Comment: What is $\subseteq _{op}$?

Comment: It means open subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your starting point is correct, you just have to take care of the details and finish it.

By the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem), the fact that $f'(a)$ is an isomorphism means that, *locally*, $f$ is a diffeomorphism. More clearly, there exist a small neighbourhood $V \subseteq U$ of $a$ such that $f : V \to f(V)$ is a diffeomorphism (i.e. a local change of variable), therefore you may apply the change of variable theorem on every $B(a,r) \subseteq V$, for the characteristic function of $f(V)$, call it $\chi$:

$$\int \limits _{f(B(a,r))} \chi \ \Bbb d x = \int \limits _{B(a,r)} \chi \circ f \ | \det f'(x) | \ \Bbb d x .$$

Now, apply the [mean value theorem for integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_Value_Theorems_for_Definite_Integrals) (the statement that I link to is given in $\Bbb R$, but in fact it is valid in general): there exist $y_r \in f(B(a,r))$ and $x_r \in B(a,r)$ (so, in particular, $\chi (y_r) = \chi (f(x_r)) = 1$) such that

$$\int \limits _{f(B(a,r))} \chi \ \Bbb d x = \chi (y_r) \text{ vol } (f(B(a,r))) = \text{ vol } (f(B(a,r))) \\
\int \limits _{B(a,r)} \chi \circ f \ \Bbb d x = \chi \circ f (x_r) \ | \det f'(x_r) | \ \text{ vol } (B(a,r)) = \text{ vol } (B(a,r)) \ | \det f'(x_r) |$$

which, combined with the change of variable theorem implies

$$\text{ vol } (f(B(a,r))) = \text{ vol } (B(a,r)) \ | \det f'(x_r) |$$

so that

$$| \det f'(x_r) | = \frac {\text{ vol } (f(B(a,r)))} {\text{ vol } (B(a,r))} .$$

Finally, for $r \to 0$, notice that $x_r \to a$ (because the balls $B(a, r)$ stretch down to $a$ for $r \to 0$), so we may write

$$| \det f'(a) | = \lim \limits _{r \to 0} | \det f'(x_r) | = \lim \limits _{r \to 0} \frac {\text{ vol } (f(B(a,r)))} {\text{ vol } (B(a,r))}.$$

($\text{ vol }$ means the $m$-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R^m$.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By the inverse function theorem, $f$ is a diffeomorphism of some neighborhood of $a.$